# QEmu 1.4.0: no more internet

Tags: qemu, kvm

I've just upgraded qemu, and my virtual Windows XP no longer finds a network card.

I'm not sure what version I was running before, but I'm now running QEmu 1.4.0. I launch QEmu with the following command:

qemu-kvm -hda /opt/WinXP2010.img -smb /path/to/shared/dir -m 1024

I'm running Gentoo Linux with a 3.8.13 kernel, and when I updated QEmu, I got some messages about adding support for vhost-net, etc, to my kernel (described here: http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU). I've turned on all these options, but I'm not really sure what I have to do next. Everything just seemed to work before, and now it doesn't, and I'm feeling a little overwhelmed by it all.

I should add: I don't think it's that virtual Windows doesn't find a network card at all. I get the "add new hardware wizard" when I start up, but then it doesn't know where to find a driver (I'm not a Windows user AT ALL, so if this is some basic Windows thing, forgive my noobness).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading through the documentation for many different Linux distributions, I've found a solution that works for me: I just needed to specify the type of network I'm using. This command works for me:

qemu-kvm -net nic,model=rtl8139 -net user -hda /opt/WinXP2010.img  -smb /path/to/shared/dir -m 1024

It seems like model=virtio is the recommended way to go, but I couldn't get the latest virtio driver to work. Fine with me, the Realtek driver does its job.